# Can systemd be used as an inetd/xinetd replacement without being an init?

Tags: systemd, services, unix-sockets, inetd, socket-activation

Can systemd be configured (in runtime or compile time) to serve as a simple process supervisor, not as `/sbin/init`?

If yes, are there tutorials and other documentation to follow to make customized non-init-systemd setups?

If no, what other thing should be used for UNIX-socket-activated services apart from plain `openbsd-inetd` (which, for example, cannot chown/chmod the sockets)?